# visual studio 2013 remote debugging - no symbols loaded after re-attaching

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013

Consider the following remote debugging sequence on a vs2013 VB web application:

- *Step 1*: 'attach to process' menu, connect to remote x64 debugger service (see image), attach to w3wp.exe. I can debug just fine (I see all symbols loaded on the modules window.)

[image]

- *Step 2*: stop debugging, reproduce Step 1. Nothing has changed - it should reload symbols and resume debugging as normal. However **there are no symbols loaded now and the breakpoints will not be hit!**

I cannot figure out why is this happening and how to recover from the situation. Tried a number of things to no avail:
1. clean & rebuild
2. closing vs, deleting bin and obj, clean & rebuild

Advanced Compiler Settings:
[image]

Visual Studio Debugger Settings:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure your code is not optimized (you can see that in the modules window) and try restarting w3wp.exe process if possible. You can create .ini file to prevent optimization of your code thus making it loadable and debugable.

Comment: Confirmed not optimised (see settings above). I have killed w3wp.exe, browsed to a page, w3wp.exe gets recreated, symbols still not being loaded.

Comment: The problem is, those settings (enable optimizations) not always work. Because website gets automatically recompiled by IIS/ASP.NET process ignoring any settings from VS. This website is then stored in the .NET Framework Cache. The only way to make sure it's really not optimized is checking it in the Modules windows once you have attached to the w3wp.exe process.

Comment: The only sequence that worked is 
1.stop debugging
2.close visual studio
3.kill remote w3wp.exe
4.browse page - w3wp.exe recreated
5.open visual studio
6.attach via remote debugger
7.breakpoint is hit.

However I am unable to consistently reproduce the above. It worked once and I was able to verify optimisation column value is 'no' on the modules window.